# Highcharts: Select a single chart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working with highcharts to make a dashboard.
Now I search each chart with the jquery for each function, to find which chart is wider than the window to make it responsive.
So I have to define the width for each chart.

If a chart is wider than the window, I want to define

```
width = $(window).width().
```

with

```
$(".dashboard").highcharts({
    chart: {
        width: width, //320
     },
});
```

I can select all charts, but how do I select a single chart?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for .each() and Highcharts [setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize)

```
$(".dashboard").each(function () {
  //Test if chart is wider than window here and update below
  $(this).highcharts.setSize(Number width, Number height);
});
```

Although if you are just looking for responsive charts you can set your highcharts container to 100% width and it will automatically happen.

```
<div id="chartcontainer" width='100%'></div>
```

Comment: Ok now the charts the width was applied are empty

Comment: If i place the code at the end, nothing happens and if i place it in $( document ).ready, highcharts doesnt exists.

This is the full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656402/gridster-with-highcharts-make-specific-chart-smaller-and-recalculate